# How do I find if a checkbox is checked in Selenium Webdriver JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am using selenium webdriver in Javascript.

I have a checkbox that I want to find out which are checked and which are not checked. I can display them but unable to figure out if the checked is true or not. I tried isEnabled and checked.

[image: This is the checkbox with the different colors]

```
it("Display Select List Options", async function() {
    // Identify Componenets in select list = md-clickable
    //options have to be visible

      await dashboardPage.run();
      await dashboardPage.componentByIdWithClick("select_14"); //Click on Select List

      let results = await dashboardPage.componentsByClass('md-clickable');    

      for (let i in results){
        console.log(await results[i].getText())  }        
        await driver.sleep(4000);
      });
```

This is what I get but want it to say (i.e. Blue is checked, Red is Not Checked,etc.) :

[image: ?]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the HTML you are working with as a block of code.

Comment: And please include the code you have tried in order to determine if it is checked or not.

Comment: the code is up there

Comment: HTML code. Not just JavaScript. We need to see the HTML code as well.